# How to bind prop in Client-side component API in svelte?

Tags: binding, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

In the svelte docs: [Client-side component API](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api), there is no way described to bind a prop to a component mounted through client-side component API.

#### Consider the Usecase:

```js
import comp from './comp.svelte'

let value = 33

new comp({ 
    target: document.getElementById('#iframe').contentDocument
                .getElementById('#container')
    props: {
        bindme: value // how to actually bind?
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't. The client-side API has many limitations around reactivity and slots.

Try to limit the use of the client-side API to top level components. You can also use events and [`$on`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api-$on) or work with [stores](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) if you really need to use the client-side API.